# Requiring at least one selection only if another value is true

Tags: javascript, yup

Having trouble nailing down this validation schema as Yup is new to me. Basically what I am looking for here is if `hasCategory` is `true` then I want at least one of the categories to be selected. Right now my schema shape is:

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object()
.shape({
  hasCategory: Yup.boolean().required('Yes or No must be selected for special ad category'),
  cat1: Yup.boolean(),
  cat2: Yup.boolean(),
  cat3: Yup.boolean(),
  cat4: Yup.boolean(),
});
```

So if `hasCategory` is `true` then I need one of `cat1`, `cat2`, `cat3`, or `cat4` to be `true`. If `hasCategory` is false then I don't need any of those categories to be truthy.

Any nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```js
Yup.object()
  .shape({
    hasCategory: Yup.boolean().required(
      "Yes or No must be selected for special ad category"
    ),
    cat1: Yup.boolean(),
    cat2: Yup.boolean(),
    cat3: Yup.boolean(),
    cat4: Yup.boolean()
  })
  .test("hasCategory", "At least one category must be true", (value)=>{
    // if hasCategory is false then test passes 
    if(!value.hasCategory) return true;
    // if any one of the categories is true then test passes otherwise if all are false it fails
    return value.cat1|value.cat2|value.cat3|value.cat4
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `test()` method provided by Yup to perform conditional validations.

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  hasCategory: Yup.boolean().required('Yes or No must be selected for special ad category'),
  cat1: Yup.boolean(),
  cat2: Yup.boolean(),
  cat3: Yup.boolean(),
  cat4: Yup.boolean(),
}).test('hasCategory', 'At least one category must be selected', function(value) {
  if (this.parent.hasCategory) {
    return this.parent.cat1 || this.parent.cat2 || this.parent.cat3 || this.parent.cat4;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
});
```

#### Explination

using `test()` allows you to get the value of the scheme and its context is set to the parent object giving you access to the fields. itll return true when it passes and false if it fails. theres also if `hasCategory` is true it checks if the others are true as well. and if its false then it just passes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array named ***catArray*** instead of multiple property cat1, cat2, ....

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object()
.shape({
  hasCategory: Yup.boolean().required('Yes or No must be selected for special ad category'),
  catArray: Yup.array().when('hasCategory', 
  {
     is: true,
     then: Yup.array().min(1, 'One field must be checked'), 
  })
});
```

I hope this way is useful.